# How to decide whether a computer graphics question should be asked on SO, Computer Graphics, or Game Dev?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, stack-exchange

We have *three* boards for which it's acceptable to ask computer graphics questions; [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), and [Computer Graphics](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/) (and arguably [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), since there's a [graphics](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) tag there).

Given this, **how should I decide whether a given graphics question I want to ask is right for one of these sites?**

Comment: What specific question? The whole stackexchange universe likes specifics.  Could you please click edit and add a specific question into the post so the community has something to work with?

Comment: Depends on the question.  Tada.

Comment: I don't have a specific question to ask right now, but that's kind of the point.  I don't want to have to come here every single time I have a graphics question to ask, I just want to ask the damned thing.

Comment: Read the Help section for each site. Is there one that mentions your topic in its help/on-topic section? Then that's the one you ask it on.

Comment: Thankfully, this is StackOverflow, we don't have to answer questions about a hypothetical problem with no concrete example. Obviously, there is a bit of overlap between some of those places, so a question may work in more than one place -- or not at all -- depending on the actual question itself. And if a question does fit in more than one place, the right thing to do is to post it in one location only instead of cross-posting the question in more than one place at the same time.