# Distinction between programming, web development, and stack overflow

Tags: discussion

When I look at the list of exchanges on StackExchange, I see a number of exchanges related to computer software programming, such as Stack Overflow, Computer Graphics, Programming, and Web Applications.  How do I determine which I should use for posting questions?

Comment: Take a tour of the site (click "help" then "tour" in the header bar). It will tell you what the site is used for, what kinds of questions are accepted and point you to the "on-topic" section where you can read more.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275082/what-kind-of-questions-belong-on-stack-exchange-and-stack-overflow, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314750/how-to-decide-whether-a-computer-graphics-question-should-be-asked-on-so-comput, ...

Comment: You even get a badge for reading the entire tour page :)

Comment: Note that [webapps.se] is not about *programming* web applications; it's for "power users of web applications". There may be questions within that are quite "programming-like"; for instance, cell formulae in Google Sheets, but it's generally geared toward end-users.

Answer (score 5):

Read each site's on-topic guidelines (for example [on-topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) to find where you actually can ask the questions.  Often a question will be on-topic for multiple communities or off-topic for all communities.

If your question is on-topic for multiple communities try to figure out which community perspective would be more helpful for an answer.  For example, a [debugging question about OpenGL could be posted on either Stack Overflow or Computer Graphics](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-questions-about-debugging-opengl-shaders-on-topic) as long as it has a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  **Do not cross-post** by asking the same exact question multiple places.  If you still can't decide on the best home for a question, feel free to ask a [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) on meta with your potential question.